# TFS source viewer in project portal

Tags: tfs, viewer

We're using TFS as source control provider and for the project management (documents, ...). Maybe I missed something completely, but is there a possibilty to view source code directly from the project portal? I know that source code is not stored there, but does there exist a 3rd-party viewer or something? It would be nice sometimes not to simply have a quick look at the source files without retrieving them from TFS.

Any ideas/tools/addins?

Thanks for any hints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Team System Web Access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb980951.aspx).

It is standalone portal which enables you to see source, work items, reports, documents, builds etc. Like from Team explorer integrated in Visual Studio.

[alt text http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb676728.TeamSystemWebAccess(en-us,MSDN.10).png](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/bb676728.TeamSystemWebAccess(en-us,MSDN.10).png)